# Стандартные переменные Asterisk

Tags: linux, centos, asterisk

Нужно писать разговор в файл.

`exten => +1234567890,1,Set(fname=${DATETIME}-${CALLERIDNUM})`

...Голосовое меню...

`exten => 3,1,MixMonitor(/home/AsteriskCallRecording/${fname}.wav)`
`same => 2,Dial(SIP/sip.zoiper2, 20, t)`

Нет записи, то есть астериск не может дать имя файлу, вместо датавремя+номерзвонящего - пустота. Проверял в CLI, убирал доступ на запись в директорию и был вывод

> unable to open /home/AsteriskCallRecotding/.wav

Правлю  `${fname}` на рандомный текст - `record`.
`exten => 3,1,MixMonitor(/home/AsteriskCallRecording/record.wav)`

Все работает, записывается в файл.
Пробовал в Set ставить имя конкретное, но из-за `${fname}` в следующей строке опять ничего.

Вопрос, почему переменные не работают, как нужно правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем [мануалы](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Standard+Channel+Variables):

- ${DATETIME} * - Current date time in the format: DDMMYYYY-HH:MM:SS (**Deprecated**; use ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S)})
- ${CALLERID(num)} * - Caller ID Number only